# Upload file to server using class dll

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

It is fairly easy to upload a file using web form. But I need to accomplish this through DLL.
I have classic ASP page with file upload form and I need to create an object that handles the uploaded file from customer and save the file to the server. What would be the best way to approach this? I have been digging and came across Web.HttpPostedFile and HttpWebRequest. but I don't know which route to take.

Also, I am a bit confused about how to pass the uploaded file to DLL so my class can upload and manipulate the file.  is there any sample code for this?
Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: File uploads are tricky in Classic ASP.  There's a script called freeaspupload you can use which comes with documentation - see http://www.freeaspupload.net/ ,  or there are several third party components you can use, eg Persits AspUpload or ABCUpload.  Third party compnents offer more, but they need to be purchased and installed on your server.  http://www.aspupload.com/,  http://www.websupergoo.com/abcupload-1.htm

Comment: The things you mention are ASP.NET, classic ASP is something different and can't have DLL file (in the meaning you can't compile classic ASP code into DLL because it's a scripting language). Removed the tag as it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make much sense, as you kind of asking "I have old car's parts and I need to assemble one by using a wheel". What? That doesn't make sense.

A dll is a container for some code. You do not use a container per se to upload a file. You should search for "classic asp upload file sample", find a solution, give it a try and come back with a specific problem.

I also noticed HTTPS tag, the idea with **S**, is that you don't care whether it is secure or not from the programming perspective. If you are able to use HTTP, it is trivial to upload files to HTTPS - just change the URL in the UI. The server *code* itself wouldn't change. What will change is the server hosting configuration, you would have to add certificate details.

Comment: well, I created dll to grab variable from submitted ASP form and send the server to work with the variable using Server.CreateObject.  SO what you saying that this cannot be done for uploading a file. Can I pass the uploaded file to dll so it can mange the file as far as saving it and so on?

Comment: @user2373025 - he's saying that a .dll does not inherently manage files. You can use one that someone else created, or roll your own (which is what it sounds like you are trying to do) - but the nature of doing so is far and away more different than the initial question.

Comment: @user2373025 what I am trying to say is that dll is just a logical container for your code. What your code does is irrelevant. dll is just where you would store the compiled source code. If you can show your code with a particular problem that would help. To your question: " Can I pass the uploaded file to dll ", you would upload a file, wait until it finishes and pass a file name to your worker process. A worker process accepts a file name (as a string) and reads a file, parses the content and executes the work. Is that helpful?

Comment: Thank for your useful information. Well, All I need to do is to write a class dll so when It gets called from ASP page to save the file to the server. (I am not sure if it is possible):
<form action="test.asp"  ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input  type="file" name="file1" >
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="submit"> </form>

Comment: and the dll that is not working is :
Imports System.Web
Public Class Class1
 Public Function test(ByVal thefile As String) As String
    Dim Loop1 As Integer
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim MyFileCollection As HttpFileCollection = thefile

 For Loop1 = 0 To MyFileCollection.Count - 1
    ' Create a new file name.
    TempFileName = "C:\TempFiles\File_" & CStr(Loop1)
    ' Save the file.
    MyFileCollection(Loop1).SaveAs(TempFileName)
 Next Loop1
end function
End Class

Comment: But i had no luck and I dont  think  "thefile" is being pass to the class . Is there any other or better way of doing this?. do you have any suggestion

Comment: you mixing c#, vb and dll concepts. I would start with a basic independent example of a file upload with whatever technology you need to use. Make it work in a separate solution. And then migrate the parts to where you need.